# ASP.NET MVC web application exception handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-mvc-2, application-blocks

ASP.NET MVC web application exception handling using application blocks.

How can i configure Microsoft Application blocks for exception handling in .NET MVC2 web application logging the error to the sql database?

Comment: Have you tried any approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can write own Library bur this is not easy so i prefer  u Use Elmah

I think elmah is good because now 588,786 is downloaded so we safely to use.
You can simply install

PM> Install-Package elmah

> ELMAH with initial configuration for getting started quickly. ELMAH
>   (Error Logging Modules and Handlers) is an application-wide error
>   logging facility that is completely pluggable. It can be dynamically
>   added to a running ASP.NET web application, or even all ASP.NET web
>   applications on a machine, without any need for re-compilation or
>   re-deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about ELMAH. It is much lighter than Application Blocks and you can use it as a filter for handling errors.